# Angular Signalr cors policy

Tags: .net, angular, amazon-web-services, signalr

I have an angular application that uses signaling.
Locally I have the following architecture: an angular front that calls a dotnet gateway api that contains ocelot that calls my final api.
In the Ocelot api I declare the front url for the policy cors

My problem is deploying on AWS
So I have my angular front that goes through the api gateway aws that reacts in temp that proxy. This one calls the api gateway dotnet ocelot. To make this call I go through a load balancer.
My gateway api ocelot calls the final dotnet api through the load balancer.
Here my problem is or configure the cors policy
Because I put the url of frront in the gateway ocelot but without success